# How to add text inside an SVG element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, frontend

I would like to add text inside an element such that my intro is behind a rectangular, transparent element.
[image]
I tried adding text inside an SVG like this

```
  <svg height="150" width="500">
    <text x="100" y="30" fill="red">I love SVG!</text>
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);
      stop-opacity:0" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:1" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <ellipse cx="200" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#grad1)" />
  </svg>
```

However I can't Send the object backwards. Is this even possible?

Is there a better approach I can use to meet this objective rather than the solution I'm trying to use?

Comment: What do you mean by "behind this background" and "behind a rectangular transparent background". That's not clear.  Do you mean "in front of"?  If it is behind, it won't be visible.  You are also now talking about buttons and other HTML. Do you mean that you want to have an SVG file as a background to some HTML (eg. a `<div>`)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just talking about whether the text is behind the oval, or on top of it?

If so, just changing the order of elements fixes that:

```html
<svg height="150" width="500">
   <defs>
     <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
       <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);
                                stop-opacity:0" />
       <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:1" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <ellipse cx="200" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#grad1)" />
  <text x="100" y="30" fill="red">I love SVG!</text>
</svg>
```

Or is there something else you're trying to do? (Please note, even with the text on top of the oval, the contrast isn't that great, and it's still hard to read.)

Comment: Yes, how do I add the entire intro with all the buttons behind this background (Possibly a rectangular transparent background) I opened and closed the svg tag after the chunk of html that includes the button and intro and all - but this didn't work. I tried to reposition the element to move lower to toward the elements I want on top of it - this made my div a whole lot wider than I needed it to be. Im just trying to figure out how to have a rectangular object behind my intro section.